# Finding the homomorphism that links the linear part of a dynamical system to the nonlinear part.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, partial-derivative

here is a picture of my problem [image: My problem]

Basically what i have is that i was told i could find this homomorphism by doing the following

```
assume 
u=f(x,y,z)
v=g(x,y,z)
w=h(x,y,z)

then 
u'=(fx)x' +(fy)y' +(fz)z'
v'=(gx)x' +(gy)y' +(gz)z'
w'=(hx)x' +(hy)y' +(hz)z'
```

From this apparently i reconstruct what f,g,and h have to be. I suppose my question regards what is the point of doing this method? how do i progress here? x',y',z' are known however u' v' and w' are unknown and the im not sure how to reconstruct the functions to gain this idea of a homomorphism between the linear and nonlinear system.

In addition to attempting this, i have actually found analytical solutions to this system where

```
x(t)=e^(-2t)
y(t)=-(e^(-6t))/7
z(t)=(e^(-8t))/35
```

I dont know if that is specifically helpful to finding the homomorphism or not.

Some insight would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Not that this answers your question, but your explicit solution to the system isn't right. I get $x(t)=x_0 e^{-2t}$ to begin with, then $z(t)=(z_0+\frac17 x_0^3) e^t - \frac17 x_0^3 e^{-6t}$, and then $y(t)$ equal to something else which I haven't bothered to compute...

Comment: And another non-answer: in the question it ought to say "homeomorphism" rather than "homomorphism".